# libgdx physics system improvements

Tags: libgdx, system, physics, frame-rate

want to write my own physics in libgdx with ashley ECS framework.
So I created a physics system, but its behaviour is not good with renderind. I tought it should be frame-independent and added following code, but i dont like behaviour in this case too. Here is the code.

```
public class PhysicsSystem extends IteratingSystem {
    private float accumulator = 0;
    private static final float TIME_STEP = 1 / 120f;


    private ComponentMapper<PhysicsComponent> pcm = ComponentMapper.getFor(PhysicsComponent.class);

    public PhysicsSystem(Family family) {
        super(family);
    }

    @Override
    public void update(float deltaTime) {

        float frameTime = Math.min(deltaTime, 0.25f);
        accumulator += frameTime;

        while (accumulator >= TIME_STEP) {
            accumulator -= TIME_STEP;
            super.update(TIME_STEP);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void processEntity(Entity entity, float deltaTime) {
        PhysicsComponent physicsComponent = pcm.get(entity);

        physicsComponent.applyForce(0, -9.8f * deltaTime);

        physicsComponent.position.add(physicsComponent.velocity.x * deltaTime, 
physicsComponent.velocity.y * deltaTime);

     }
}
```

So are there any techniques to improve my physics? Any tip can help.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: will edit post for you to see) thx